# unsorted linked list implementation check full

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am working on unsorted linked list check full currently, below is my specification and implementation.

Specification:

```
#ifndef UNSORTEDLIST_H
#define UNSORTEDLIST_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
  float element;
  Node* next;
};

class UnsortedList
{
    public:
    UnsortedList();
    bool IsEmpty();
    bool IsFull();
    void ResetList();
    void MakeEmpty();
    int LengthIs();
    bool IsInTheList(float item);
    void InsertItem(float item);
    void DeleteItem(float item);
    float GetNextItem();

    private:
      Node* data;
      Node* currentPos;
      int length;
};

#endif
```

And implemetation:

```
UnsortedList::UnsortedList()
{
    length = 0;
    data = NULL;
    currentPos = NULL;
}

bool UnsortedList:: IsEmpty(){
    if(length == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool UnsortedList::IsFull(){
    Node* ptr = new Node();
    if(ptr == NULL)
      return true;
    else
    {
      delete ptr;
      return false;
    }
}

void UnsortedList::ResetList(){
   currentPos = NULL;
}

void UnsortedList::MakeEmpty()
{
   Node* tempPtr = new Node();

   while(data != NULL)
   {
     tempPtr = data;
     data = data->next;
     delete tempPtr;
   }
   length = 0;
}

int UnsortedList::LengthIs(){
    return length;
}

bool UnsortedList:: IsInTheList(float item){

Node* location = new Node();
location = data;
bool found = false;

while(location != NULL && !found)
{
    if(item == location->element)
        found = true;
    else
        location = location->next;
}
   return found;
}

void UnsortedList:: InsertItem(float item){

    Node* location = new Node();
    location->element = item;
    location->next=data;
    data = location;
    length++;
}

void UnsortedList:: DeleteItem(float item){

Node* location = data;
Node* tempPtr;

if(item == data->element){
    tempPtr = location;
    data = data->next;
}
else{
  while(!(item == (location->next) ->element) )
    location = location->next;
    tempPtr = location->next;
    location->next = (location->next)->next;
}
  delete tempPtr;
  length--;
}

float UnsortedList::GetNextItem(){
   if(currentPos == NULL)
    currentPos = data;
   else
    currentPos = currentPos->next;
   return currentPos->element;
}
```

1.In the constructor, why don't assign currentPos as null?
2.In the IsInTheList function,  Why points to pointer "next" ? Isn't next is a null pointer since it has been declared in struct as Node* next?

Comment: 1.: You should set it to null 2.:Your second question doesn't make sense. And there's quite a lot wrong with this code but I'm just answering your asked questions.

Comment: @MikeVine What I am asking is if I do Node* next in struct, hasn't the pointer "next" already been declared as null?

Comment: The entire question doesn't make sense.
If it is your implementation, why do you have questions about why it's coded a certain way?

Comment: @banshee_walk_sly where doesn't make sense, please point it out, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Ming You say "below is my specification and implementation.", then you say things like "why don't assign currentPos..." for which the answer is because you coded it incorrectly.

Comment: @banshee_walk_sly Oh, I am sorry. This isn't my code, in fact this is a piece of code from my text book. But I have to mention, I am here to ask question, please don't try to focus on who did this code.

Comment: I started writing up several potential "answers" to this question, but in the end I just had to give up. There are enough problems in this to simply suggest to (a) start rereading that book you have from the beginning, and/or (b) get a different book, then see (a). I'm not being cruel by intention here; thats just the plain harsh reality. Short of rewriting *all* of this from scratch there is little more that can functionally be done.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer value is not set to NULL value by default, you should set to to null explicitly. Also instead of using NULL, choose using nullptr.

Comment: Ok, so your point is that i suppose to do Next = nullptr in the constructor?

Comment: Since the code is not complete, as well as the question is not clear I couldn't run it on my machine and see what happens and what is supposed to be happened basically. But at this stage if you want your next pointer being assigned to a null value you can override the default constructor of the Node struct like
Node (): Next (nullptr) {};
try adding this line inside your Node Struct

Answer (score 0):

This code is rather incomplete, so it is difficult to answer your questions.

This does not contain the code to insert an item in the list, which is where I would expect both the next and currentPos pointers to be set. However, that's based on a number of assumptions.

However, I don't see where next is used in the "check full function" at all, so that question is a bit confusing.

I'll also point out that this code has a glaring memory leak. The first line in IsInTheList allocates memory for a new Node, which is immediately lost with `location = data`.

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly where you are referring to in your second question "In the check full function, Why points to pointer "next" ?"

Comment: But I do agree with initializing currentPos to null in the constructor, now that I see better how it is being used.

Comment: Apologize for the inconveniences, my second question supposes to refer to IsInTheList function.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. It's OK to use next there because it is always being manipulated in insertItem. As I stated, that `Node* location = new Node();` is a memory leak, but even more importantly, it's probably confusing. The next line changes `location` to point to `data`, which is either NULL or points to a valid Node that was created in insertItem.

Comment: Could you please explain more about why Node* location = new Node(); will cause memory leak?

Comment: The 'new Node()' allocates memory for a Node and points 'location' to it. The next line points 'location' at 'data'. At this point the memory allocated in the first line has nothing pointed at it. Therefore, you have a block of memory allocated with no pointer to it and no way to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers (like any other basic type) need to be initialized before use. A value of NULL is still a value.

The code you provided seems to be very incomplete. Is `data` supposed to be the head of your list? I am not sure how you define "fullness". If you want to test if the list is empty, you can see if your "head" of the list is null:

```
bool UnsortedList::IsEmpty() {
  if (data == NULL) {return true;}  // if there is no first element, empty
  else {return false;}              // if there is ANY element, not empty
}
```

Or more compactly:

```
bool UnsortedList::Empty() {
  return (data == NULL);
}
```

When a node is added to a linked list, we usually add the node as a whole and modify the element that came before it. For example, we might create a new node and add it using code like the following:

```
// implementation file
void UnsortedList::InsertItem(const float& item) {
  if (data == NULL) {  // no elements in list, so new node becomes the head
    data          = new Node;        // allocate memory for new node
    data->element = item;            // fill with requested data
    data->next    = NULL;            // there is no element after the tail
  }
  else {
    new_node          = new Node;    // allocate memory
    new_node->element = item         // set data
    new_node->next    = NULL;        // new end of the list, so it points to nothing

    tail->next = new_node;           // have the OLD end node point to the NEW end
    tail       = new_node;           // have the tail member variable move up
  }
}

// driver file
int main() {
  UnsortedList my_list;

  float pie = 3.14159;
  my_list.AddNode(pie);

  return 0;
}
```

Please note that I made use of a Node* member variable called tail. It is a good idea to keep track of both where the list begins and ends.

In your `IsFull` function, it will always return false since it can always create a new Node*. Except perhaps if you run out of memory, which is probably more problematic.

Your functions are rather confusing and your pointer work leaves many memory leaks. You might want to review the STL list object design [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/).